# Numpy Array, Data must be 1-dimensional

Tags: python, matlab, pandas, numpy

I am attempting to reproduce MatLab code in Python and am stumbling with a MatLab matrix.  The block of code in MatLab is below:

```
for i = 1:Np
    y = returns(:,i);
    sgn = modified_sign(y); 
    X = [ones(Tp,1) sgn.*log(prices(:,i).*volumes(:,i))];
```

I am having a hard time creating 'X' without getting the "Data Must be 1 Dimensional Error.  Below is one of my attempts, of many trying to reproduce this section of code:

```
lam = np.empty([Tp,Np]) * np.nan
for i in range(0,Np):
    y=returns.iloc[:,i]
    sgn = modified_sign(y)
    #X = np.array([[np.ones([Tp,1]),np.multiply(np.multiply(sgn,np.log(prices.iloc[:,i])),volumes.iloc[:,i])]])
    X = np.concatenate([np.ones([Tp,1]),np.column_stack(np.array([sgn*np.log(prices.iloc[:,i])*volumes[:,i]]))],axis=1)
```

Tp and Np are the length and width of the prices series

```
crsp['PRC'].to_frame().shape = (9455,1)
Tp, Np = crsp['PRC'].to_frame().shape
```

Tr and Nr are the length and width of the returns series

```
crsp['RET'].to_frame().shape = (9455,1)
Tr, Nr = crsp['RET'].to_frame().shape
```

Tv and Nv are the length and width of the volume series

```
crsp['VOL'].to_frame().shape = (9455,1)
Tv, Nv = crsp['VOL'].to_frame().shape
```

The ones array:

```
np.ones([Tp,1])
```

would be (9455,1)

Sample Volume Data:

```
    DATE    VOLAVG
1979-12-04  8880.9912591051
1979-12-05  8867.545284586622
1979-12-06  8872.264687564875
1979-12-07  8876.922134551494
1979-12-10  8688.765365448506
1979-12-11  8695.279567657451
1979-12-12  8688.865033222592
1979-12-13  8684.095435684647
1979-12-14  8684.534550736667
1979-12-17  8879.694444444445
```

Sample Price Data

```
    DATE    AVGPRC
1979-12-04  25.723484200567693
1979-12-05  25.839463450495863
1979-12-06  26.001899852224145
1979-12-07  25.917628864251874
1979-12-10  26.501898917349788
1979-12-11  26.448652367425804
1979-12-12  26.475906537182407
1979-12-13  26.519610746585908
1979-12-14  26.788873713159944
1979-12-17  26.38583047822484
```

Sample Return Data

```
    DATE    RET
1979-12-04  0.008092780873338423
1979-12-05  0.004498557619416754
1979-12-06  0.006266692192175238
1979-12-07  -0.0032462182943131523
1979-12-10  0.022292999386413825
1979-12-11  -0.002011180868938034
1979-12-12  0.001029925340138238
1979-12-13  0.0016493553247958206
1979-12-14  0.010102153877941776
1979-12-17  -0.015159499602784175
```

What I am ultimately trying to achieve is an (9455,2) array where X.iloc[:,0]=1 and X.iloc[:,2]=log(price)*volume for each row.

I referenced the MatLab to Numpy document online (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) and checked out various other StackOverflow posts to no avail.

For context, modified_sign is an external function, prices is a DataFrame slice, as is returns.  Np is the width (think df.shape[1]) of the price DataFrame and Tp is df.shape[0].  This is esentially creating a column of 1s and log(price)*volume to be used in a regression for each series of returns where each df is (TxN) where T is dates and N is securities.  Any guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since some variables / functions are missing and we cannot reproduce the issue, can you print the shapes of the arguments to np.concatenate prior to its call?

Comment: Even better: add some "toy" data to turn your Python code into a [mcve].

Comment: Added toy data as requested

Comment: Keep in mind that MATLAB matrix is 2d or higher.  `numpy` arrays can be 1d.  `numpy` has a `np.matrix` class that is always 2d, which can make the transition from MATLAB easier.  But in the long run it is best to use the regular `np.array`.

Comment: Thanks I tried using the matrix function before to no avail.  I appreciate your help.  I keep getting the "Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional" error

Comment: Other SO questions indicate that `Data must be 1-dimensional` is a common Pandas error message.  I added a `pandas` tag.  You need to tell us which line is producing the error.

Comment: @RobertGarrison; Don't use the matrix data type. It is poorly supported by the rest of the python software ecosystem because it is almost never what you actually want in practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that numpy can have 1D array (vectors) while MATLAB cannot. So when you create the `np.ones([Tp,1])` array, it is creating a 2D array where one dimension has a size of 1. In MATLAB, that is considered a "vector", but in numpy it isn't.

So what you need to do is give `np.ones` a single value. This will result in a vector (unlike in MATLAB where it will result in a 2D square matrix). The same rule applies to `np.zeros` and any other function that takes dimensions as inputs.

So this should work:

```
X = np.column_stack([np.ones(Tp), sgn*np.log(prices.iloc[:,1])*volumes.iloc[:,1]])
```

That being said, you are losing most of the advantage of using pandas by doing it this way. It would be much better to combine the DataFrames into one using the dates as indices, then create a new column with the calculation. Assuming the dates are the indices, something like this should work (if the dates are indices use `set_index` to make them indices):

```
data = pd.concat([returns, prices, volumes], axis=1)
data['sign'] = modified_sign(data['ret')
data['X0'] = 1
data['X1'] = data['sign']*np.log(data['AVGPRC'])*data['VOLAVG']
```

Of course you would replace `X0` and `X1` with more informative names, and I am not sure you even need `X0` using this approach, but that would get you a much easier-to-work-with data structure.

Also, if your dates are strings you should convert them to pandas dates. They are much nicer to work with than strings.